# Best practice for multiple uiviewcontrollers

Tags: objective-c, iphone

i have a application that will have multiple uiviewcontrollers, the navigation in the application is not in a hierarchy, the controllers should all be able to be invokedon a need to be displayed basis.

What is the best way of modeling this kind of flow?, using UINavigationController?, or AppDelegate for switching viewcontrollers? etc.

some coding examples would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what you said, I think you could use a UITabBarController.

I recommend you [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) of the iOS Reference Library which describe several ways to manage UiViewControllers in iPhone apps.
What you need is in 4 last sections of the document.

Hope this helps !